# How does this lambda function work exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Can anybody explain to me please what exactly does this lambda function do?

```
from collections import Counter

def solve(a):
    c = Counter(a)
    return sorted(a, key=lambda k: (-c[k], k))
```

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: what is input to `solve` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda function is just like any other function, it's just expressed in a more compact way - so breaking it down:

```
lambda k : ( -c[k], k )
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def lambdafunction(k):
    return (-c[k], k )
```

Where c is some in-scope variable - which per your `solve` function is a Counter.

The contents of that counter are keys and variables, and the lambda extracts those values and multiplies them by minus one, it then builds a tuple containing this extracted, negated value as the first entry, and the key as the second entry. These tuples are then used to perform the sort on the object to be solved, sorting the elements by frequency - most frequent first, with tie-breaking (i.e. where two or more elements share the same frequency) performed on the natural object.

e.g.

```
alist = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d"]
solve(alist)
>>  ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd']
```

Internally, there's a Counter which contains the values:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 6, 'd': 2})
```

The lambda function converts these to tuples, which it associates with each element of the list before sorting them:

```
( -6, "c" )
( -3, "b" ) 
( -2, "a" )
( -2, "d" )
```

So all the "c" items appear at the top of the list, because the internally calculated tuples associated with them `( -6, "c" )` come first.

Using a lambda function like this within the `sorted` function gives `sorted` the flexibility to sort using whatever method you like - you define the function used to describe exactly what aspects of the collection you want sorted.

Answer (score 1):

`Counter(a)` counts how many times each element is present in `a`, so this sorts `a` from most often element to least often element and when counts are the same it sorts alphabetically